# .Net MAUI app not starting on IOS : NullReferenceException. in public App()

Tags: visual-studio, ios-simulator, maui, .net-8.0

My MAUI .Net app crashes on launch.

I have System.NullReferenceException

on : `public App()`

called from:  `UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));`

Stacktrace:

```
at ObjCRuntime.Class.ResolveFullTokenReference(UInt32 token_reference) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:line 422
   at ObjCRuntime.Class.ResolveTokenReference(UInt32 token_reference, UInt32 implicit_token_type) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:line 463
   at ObjCRuntime.Class.ResolveMethodTokenReference(UInt32 token_reference) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:line 449
   at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetMethodFromToken(UInt32 token_ref) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:line 820
   at Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread(Action action) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:line 782
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.MainThread.InvokeOnMainThread[UITraitCollection](Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.AppInfoImplementation.get_RequestedTheme()
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.AppInfo.get_RequestedTheme()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application..ctor(Boolean setCurrentApplication)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application..ctor()
   at MauiApp2.App..ctor() in C:\Users\samuelcarrier\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\App.xaml.cs:line 5
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Constructor(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceIdentifier, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ServiceAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].GetOrAdd(ServiceIdentifier key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[IApplication](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 58
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 94
   at MauiApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\samuelcarrier\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 14
```

How can I debug that to find the source of the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did you use [Pair to mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-8.0)? And does this error still happen if you create a default maui project?

Comment: Deffault project is fine, a new project with all the same files is fine, it something that as to do with project file or iOS plist file or something. It dosen't do it when I choose an other platformm. Only iOS.

Comment: So is there any difference in plist file or project file?

Comment: By the way, did you use [pair to mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-8.0) or [hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Of course  It's paired to Mac, the simulator starts but when it gets to construct the App, it craches on null reference.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Nothing significant in the Plist and project file. And project file must be quite good because it runs on windows platform

Comment: That's so weird! All the same file and no significant changes in plist and project file.. Then have you added some third party nuget?

Comment: You may also check the Link Behavior in iOS Build Section.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your issue was resolved. If not, please try removing your bin and obj folder and try. I just got the same error. After removing my bin and obj folder, it worked fine when I paired to my mac and tried running the app in a IOS simulator.